# Including parenthesis when joining dataframes using rlike in pyspark

Tags: regex, apache-spark, pyspark, rlike

I have 2 pyspark dataframes that I am trying to join where some of the values in the columns have parenthesis.
For example one of the values is

```
"Mangy (Dog)"
```

If I try joining like so:

```
df1.join(df2 expr("df1.animal rlike df2.animal_stat")
```

I don't get any results.
So I tried filtering using `rlike` just to see if I am able to capture the values.

The filtering worked on all values except those with parenthesis. For example when i try to filter like so:

```
df.filter(col('animal').rlike("Mangy (Dog)")).show()
```

I don't get any results.

However, if I filter with `rlike("Mangy")` or `rlike("(Dog)"` it seems to work.  Even though I specified parenthesis in `(Dog)`.

Is there a way to make rlike to include parenthesis in its matches?

**EDIT:**
I have 2 dataframes `df1` and `df2` like so:

```
+-----------------+-------+
|           animal| origin|
+-----------------+-------+
|      mangy (dog)|Streets|
|              Cat|  house|
|[Bumbling] Bufoon| Utopia|
|          Cheetah|  Congo|
|(Sprawling) Snake| Amazon|
+-----------------+-------+

+-------------------+-----------+
|        animal_stat|destination|
+-------------------+-----------+
|              ^dog$|      House|
|              ^Cat$|    Streets|
|^[Bumbling] Bufoon$|     Circus|
|          ^Cheetah$|        Zoo|
|      ^(Sprawling)$|  Glass Box|
+-------------------+-----------+
```

I am trying to join the two using `rlike` using the following method:

```
dff1=df1.alias('dff1')
dff2=df2.alias('dff2')

combine=dff1.join(dff2, expr("dff1.animal rlike dff2.animal_stat"), how='left')
.drop(dff2.animal_stat)
```

I would like the output dataframe to be like so:

```
+-----------------+-------+-----------+
|           animal| origin|destination|
+-----------------+-------+-----------+
|      mangy (dog)|Streets|      House|
|              Cat|  house|    Streets|
|[Bumbling] Bufoon| Utopia|     Circus|
|          Cheetah|  Congo|        Zoo|
|(Sprawling) Snake| Amazon|  Glass Box|
+-----------------+-------+-----------+
```

Answer (score 2):

Edit:

```
combine = df1.alias('df1').join(
    df2.withColumn('animal_stat', F.regexp_replace(F.regexp_replace(F.regexp_replace(F.regexp_replace('animal_stat', '\\(', '\\\\('), '\\)', '\\\\)'), '\\[', '\\\\['), '\\]', '\\\\]')).alias('df2'), 
    F.expr('df1.animal rlike df2.animal_stat'),
    'left'
)
```

---

If you're not using any regex, you probably want to use `like` instead of `rlike`. For example, you can do

```
df1.join(df2, expr("df1.animal like concat('%', df2.animal_stat, '%')"))
```

---

To do a filter, you can try

```
df.filter(col('animal').like("%Mangy (Dog)%")).show()
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I am actually using regex. Is there a way to use the `rlike` in joins where you dont specify parts of the string?
I was filtering in order to troubleshoot, but my main use for `rlike` is to join on columns that have regex. I have edited my post to show the same.

Comment: the regex does not match for the first and last row

Comment: also how could you tell whether the brackets are part of the regular expression or not? like, maybe you're trying to match any character in `[Bumbling]` because you enclosed it in square brackets?

Comment: In my use case brackets (parentheses or square) will never be part of a regular expression. It should be part of the string to be matched to

Comment: @thentangler see the edited answer? I think you can escape the parentheses using backslashes before doing an `rlike` join.

Comment: Thank You I will try that. 
But can we replace the parentehsis with a blank instead? Like
 `F.regexp_replace('animal_stat', '\\(', ' ')` ?

Comment: You could, it depends on whether you want to keep the parenthesis in the pattern to match

Answer (score 0):

`.rlike()` is the same as `.like()` except it uses regex. You need to escape the parentheses. Try filtering like this:

```py
df.filter(col('animal').rlike("Mangy \(Dog\)")).show()
```

Not sure I can help with the original join issue without some sample data.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have edited my post and added the sample data for the `rlike` join.